# JMX authentication

Tags: authentication, jmx

```
$ cd $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/management
$ cp jmxremote.password.template jmxremote.password
$ chmod u=rw jmxremote.password
$ vi jmxremote.password
```

Set a password for "monitorRole" and "controlRole":

```
monitorRole 12monitor
controlRole 55control
```

After then when I run JMX server on my machine I got following error.

```
# java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -Dcom.sun.m
agement.jmxremote.authenticate=true  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -D
java.rmi.server.host=47.168.96.31  com.example.Main
Error: Password file read access must be restricted: /root/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_29
/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.password
```

When I change the file permission with the oen of the following commands jmx server works.

```
# chmod 400  jmxremote.password
```

or

```
# chmod 600  jmxremote.password
```

But I could not connect it through username/password defined in jmxremote.password file

Comment: As a note make sure you don't have any whitespace after the passwords in the password file...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add new username/password for JMX authorization, authentication has to be defined
by adding the username in to jmxremote.access file. it should be like when adding username "admin"

```
>monitorRole   readonly
>admin         readonly
>controlRole   readwrite \
          create javax.management.monitor.*,javax.management.timer.* \
          unregister
```

Comment: At windows machine, to change jmxremote.password file permission. follow the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/security-windows.html