# Glassfish 3.1 to enable JMX without modifiying JVM but default Admin-Service

Tags: glassfish-3, jmx

I openned a session about how to enable jmx on glassfish server 3.1 before then replied my own question .
[JMX authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596759/jmx-authentication/10872404#10872404)

But for now  I have two Linux machines and installed same glasfish server 3.1.
First one is not required any special JVM settings to enable remotejmx. However
Second one is not connected through same settings so it is required to add the following jvm settings. (besides $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.password and $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/management/jmxremote.access).

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=yourhostname 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8686
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

For both glassfish servers I have checked the server-config.
Do you believe glassfish server 3.1 is not working steady?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reset the admin password then I am able to connect the Glassfish server over JMX connection with default setting (no additional JVM parameters)

```
#asadmin change-admin-password
```